# Kurento media server recording is silent

Tags: webrtc, kurento

Basing on magic-mirror example I've tried to save result MP4 to file. Video is saved well, but audio is muted.

How to enable audio stream in kurento?

**UPDATE**
*Server code that creates endpoints and pipelines:*

```
 ...
 MediaPipeline pipeline = kurento.createMediaPipeline();
 ...

String createWebRTCEndpoint(MediaPipeline pipeline, String uri, String exchange, String sdp) {
    RecorderEndpoint rep = new RecorderEndpoint.Builder(pipeline, uri)
        .stopOnEndOfStream()
        .withMediaProfile(MediaProfileSpecType.MP4)
        .build();
    WebRtcEndpoint webRtcEndpoint = new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(pipeline)
        .build();
    webRtcEndpoint.connect(rep);
    rep.connect(webRtcEndpoint);
    rep.record();
    final String result = webRtcEndpoint.processOffer(sdp);
    synchronized (pipelinesAcc) {
        pipelines.put(exchange, new Tuple<>(pipeline, new Date()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

*SDP:*

```
v=0
o=Mozilla-SIPUA-35.0.1 15423 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=SIP Call
t=0 0
a=ice-ufrag:358ccbc2
a=ice-pwd:c40707c14349a6eb2b7fabb670c06c9c
a=fingerprint:sha-256 B2:B5:89:8A:44:B9:BB:E6:EA:7A:AD:54:75:66:3C:B2:4A:89:CE:EA:22:81:BA:18:83:96:2D:A4:C3:87:E1:63
m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=ptime:20
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=sendrecv
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=setup:actpass
a=rtcp-mux
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 172.28.151.12 62452 typ host
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 172.28.151.12 62454 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 1692467199 195.234.75.189 62452 typ srflx raddr 172.28.151.12 rport 62452
a=candidate:2 2 UDP 1692467198 195.234.75.189 62454 typ srflx raddr 172.28.151.12 rport 62454
m=video 9 RTP/SAVPF 120 126 97
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f
a=sendonly
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
a=setup:actpass
a=rtcp-mux
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 172.28.151.12 51748 typ host
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 172.28.151.12 60009 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 1692467199 195.234.75.189 51748 typ srflx raddr 172.28.151.12 rport 51748
a=candidate:2 2 UDP 1692467198 195.234.75.189 60009 typ srflx raddr 172.28.151.12 rport 60009
```

**UPDATE-2**

```
kurento-media-server -v
Version: 5.0.4
Found modules:
    Module: 'core' version '5.0.4'
    Module: 'elements' version '5.0.4'
    Module: 'filters' version '5.0.4'
```

Comment: ¿Could you share the source code lines where you instantiate your RecorderEndpoint and connect it to the WebRtcEndpoint/Filter? ¿Could you also share the SDP negotiated by the WebRtcEndpoint on your pipeline? That information would be extremely helpful for understanding what's causing your issue.

Comment: @lulop just added expected

Comment: We were not able to reproduce the problem. Could you give us the result of this command so that we know the KMS version you're using? "kurento-media-server -v"

Comment: @lulop just updated my post

Comment: We have just released KMS v5.1.0. Please, try with that new version which is fixing a lot of bugs. If the problem persist in that version, let us know.

Comment: @lulop thank you! Looks it is works, could you please also help me to select correct package for reference example from this my newbie post http://stackoverflow.com/q/28461894/149818