# Selection of correct package to work with new Kurento release

Tags: java, spring-mvc, kurento

I'm using  `kurento server v 5.1.0` to solve very simple scenario on my `Java` (spring.mvc) web application. It should capture short video and save for latter use. 
Could somebody point me what should be used as reference example for `RecorderEndpoint` - either examples based on `com.kurento.kmf.media.*` or `org.kurento.client.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have some turorial examples, you should refer to [this project](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/develop):

Specifically, an example with recording functionality can be found in [this file](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/develop/kurento-one2one-call-advanced/src/main/java/org/kurento/tutorial/one2onecalladv/CallHandler.java):

In addition, `org.kurento.client.*` containst the API, but also some basic unit tests. The one for the recorder is [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-java/blob/develop/kurento-integration-tests/kurento-client-test/src/test/java/org/kurento/client/test/RecorderEndpointTest.java)

Comment: So from most of examples I can deduce that org.* should be preferred over com.* ? Could you please edit you answer so I could accept it as acceptable.

Comment: All com.kurento.* code is legacy and unmaintained. In particular, com.kurento.kmf.media.* is an application server framework we created trying to provide a higher level of abstraction for developing applications, but it was not flexible enough and it was discontinued. Currently, our recommendation is to use directly Spring as the application server framework.